# Smallest possible runnable Mach-O executable

Tags: code-golf, tips, assembly, machine-code

What is the smallest possible runnable [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) executable on x86_64? The program can do nothing (not even returning a return code), but must be a valid executable (must run without errors).

My try:

GNU Assembler (`null.s`):

```
.text
.globl _main

_main:
    retq
```

Compilation & Linking:

```
as -o null.o null.s
ld -e _main -macosx_version_min 10.12 -o null null.o -lSystem
```

Size: **4248 bytes**

Looking at the hex values it seems there is a lot of zero padding which maybe can be removed, but I don't know how. Also I don't know if it is possible to make the exectubale run without linking libSystem...

Comment: relevant / answer: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: @JanDvorak There is even a Mach-O version of "teensy": http://osxbook.com/blog/2009/03/15/crafting-a-tiny-mach-o-executable/

Comment: This GitHub Gist could also return a tiny exectubale by defining the Mach-O header on its own: https://gist.github.com/softboysxp/1084476

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Smallest runnable Mach-O has to be at least `0x1000` bytes. Because of XNU limitation, file has to be at least of `PAGE_SIZE`.
See `xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/kern/mach_loader.c`, around line 1600.

However, if we don't count that padding, and only count meaningful payload, then minimal file size runnable on macOS is `0xA4` bytes.

It has to start with mach_header (or `fat_header` / `mach_header_64`, but those are bigger).

```
struct mach_header {
    uint32_t    magic;      /* mach magic number identifier */
    cpu_type_t  cputype;    /* cpu specifier */
    cpu_subtype_t   cpusubtype; /* machine specifier */
    uint32_t    filetype;   /* type of file */
    uint32_t    ncmds;      /* number of load commands */
    uint32_t    sizeofcmds; /* the size of all the load commands */
    uint32_t    flags;      /* flags */
};
```

It's size is `0x1C` bytes.
`magic` has to be `MH_MAGIC`.
I'll be using `CPU_TYPE_X86` since it's an `x86_32` executable.
`filtetype` has to be `MH_EXECUTE` for executable, `ncmds` and `sizeofcmds` depend on commands, and have to be valid.
`flags` aren't that important and are too small to provide any other value.

Next are load commands.
Header has to be exactly in one mapping, with R-X rights -- again, XNU limitations.
We'd also need to place our code in some R-X mapping, so this is fine.
For that we need a `segment_command`.

Let's look at definition.

```
struct segment_command { /* for 32-bit architectures */
    uint32_t    cmd;        /* LC_SEGMENT */
    uint32_t    cmdsize;    /* includes sizeof section structs */
    char        segname[16];    /* segment name */
    uint32_t    vmaddr;     /* memory address of this segment */
    uint32_t    vmsize;     /* memory size of this segment */
    uint32_t    fileoff;    /* file offset of this segment */
    uint32_t    filesize;   /* amount to map from the file */
    vm_prot_t   maxprot;    /* maximum VM protection */
    vm_prot_t   initprot;   /* initial VM protection */
    uint32_t    nsects;     /* number of sections in segment */
    uint32_t    flags;      /* flags */
};
```

`cmd` has to be `LC_SEGMENT`, and `cmdsize` has to be `sizeof(struct segment_command) => 0x38`.
`segname` contents don't matter, and we'll use that later.

`vmaddr` has to be valid address (I'll use `0x1000`), `vmsize` has to be valid & multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`, `fileoff` has to be `0`, `filesize` has to be smaller than size of file, but larger than `mach_header` at least (`sizeof(header) + header.sizeofcmds` is what I've used).

`maxprot` and `initprot` have to be `VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE`. `maxport` usually also has `VM_PROT_WRITE`.
`nsects` are 0, since we don't really need any sections and they'll add up to size.
I've set `flags` to 0.

Now, we need to execute some code. There are two load commands for that: `entry_point_command` and `thread_command`.
`entry_point_command` doesn't suit us: see `xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/kern/mach_loader.c`, around line 1977:

```
1977    /* kernel does *not* use entryoff from LC_MAIN.  Dyld uses it. */
1978    result->needs_dynlinker = TRUE;
1979    result->using_lcmain = TRUE;
```

So, using it would require getting DYLD to work, and that means we'll need `__LINKEDIT`, empty `symtab_command` and `dysymtab_command`, `dylinker_command` and `dyld_info_command`. Overkill for "smallest" file.

So, we'll use `thread_command`, specifically `LC_UNIXTHREAD` since it also sets up stack which we'll need.

```
struct thread_command {
    uint32_t    cmd;        /* LC_THREAD or  LC_UNIXTHREAD */
    uint32_t    cmdsize;    /* total size of this command */
    /* uint32_t flavor         flavor of thread state */
    /* uint32_t count          count of uint32_t's in thread state */
    /* struct XXX_thread_state state   thread state for this flavor */
    /* ... */
};
```

`cmd` is going to be `LC_UNIXTHREAD`, `cmdsize` would be `0x50` (see below).
`flavour` is `x86_THREAD_STATE32`, and count is `x86_THREAD_STATE32_COUNT` (`0x10`).

Now the `thread_state`. We need `x86_thread_state32_t` aka `_STRUCT_X86_THREAD_STATE32`:

```
#define _STRUCT_X86_THREAD_STATE32  struct __darwin_i386_thread_state
_STRUCT_X86_THREAD_STATE32
{
    unsigned int    __eax;
    unsigned int    __ebx;
    unsigned int    __ecx;
    unsigned int    __edx;
    unsigned int    __edi;
    unsigned int    __esi;
    unsigned int    __ebp;
    unsigned int    __esp;
    unsigned int    __ss;
    unsigned int    __eflags;
    unsigned int    __eip;
    unsigned int    __cs;
    unsigned int    __ds;
    unsigned int    __es;
    unsigned int    __fs;
    unsigned int    __gs;
};
```

So, it is indeed 16 `uint32_t`'s which would be loaded into corresponding registers before thread is started.

Adding header, segment command and thread command gives us `0xA4` bytes.

Now, time to craft the payload.
Let's say we want it to print `Hi Frand` and `exit(0)`.

Syscall convention for macOS x86_32:

- arguments passed on the stack, pushed right-to-left
- stack 16-bytes aligned (note: 8-bytes aligned seems to be fine)
- syscall number in the eax register
- call by interrupt

See more about syscalls on macOS [here](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/).

So, knowing that, here's our payload in assembly:

```
push   ebx          #; push chars 5-8
push   eax          #; push chars 1-4
xor    eax, eax     #; zero eax
mov    edi, esp     #; preserve string address on stack
push   0x8          #; 3rd param for write -- length
push   edi          #; 2nd param for write -- address of bytes
push   0x1          #; 1st param for write -- fd (stdout)
push   eax          #; align stack
mov    al, 0x4      #; write syscall number
#; --- 14 bytes at this point ---
int    0x80         #; syscall
push   0x0          #; 1st param for exit -- exit code
mov    al, 0x1      #; exit syscall number
push   eax          #; align stack
int    0x80         #; syscall
```

Notice the line before first `int 0x80`.
`segname` can be anything, remember? So we can put our payload in it. However, it's only 16 bytes, and we need a bit more.
So, at `14` bytes we'll place a `jmp`.

Another "free" space is thread state registers.
We can set anything in most of them, and we'll put rest of our payload there.

Also, we place our string in `__eax` and `__ebx`, since it's shorter than mov'ing them.

So, we can use `__ecx`, `__edx`, `__edi` to fit the rest of our payload.
Looking at difference between address of `thread_cmd.state.__ecx` and end of `segment_cmd.segname` we calculate that we need to put `jmp 0x3a` (or `EB38`) in last two bytes of `segname`.

So, our payload assembled is `53 50 31C0 89E7 6A08 57 6A01 50 B004` for first part, `EB38` for jmp, and `CD80 6A00 B001 50 CD80` for second part.

And last step -- setting the `__eip`. Our file is loaded at `0x1000` (remember `vmaddr`), and payload starts at offset `0x24`.

Here's `xxd` of result file:

```
00000000: cefa edfe 0700 0000 0300 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000010: 0200 0000 8800 0000 0000 2001 0100 0000  .......... .....
00000020: 3800 0000 5350 31c0 89e7 6a08 576a 0150  8...SP1...j.Wj.P
00000030: b004 eb38 0010 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000  ...8............
00000040: a400 0000 0700 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0500 0000 5000 0000 0100 0000  ........P.......
00000060: 1000 0000 4869 2046 7261 6e64 cd80 6a00  ....Hi Frand..j.
00000070: b001 50cd 8000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..P.............
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2410 0000  ............$...
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000                                ....
```

Pad it with anything up to `0x1000` bytes, chmod +x and run :)

P.S. About x86_64 -- 64bit binaries are required to have `__PAGEZERO` (any mapping with `VM_PROT_NONE` protection covering page at 0x0). IIRC they [Apple] didn't make it required on 32bit mode only because some legacy software didn't have it and they're afraid to break it.

Comment: This is an incredibly thorough answer. Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: I used `truncate -s 4096 foo` (with foo being the exectuable file) to make it fit `0x1000` bytes and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 6):

## 28 Bytes, Pre-compiled.

Below is a formated hex dump of the Mach-O binary.

```
00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------| |---------| |---------| |---------/
|           |           |           |           |           |           +---------- uint32_t        flags;          // Once again redundant, no flags for safety.
|           |           |           |           |           +---------------------- uint32_t        sizeofcmds;     // Size of the commands. Not sure the specifics for this, yet it doesn't particularly matter when there are 0 commands. 0 is used for safety.
|           |           |           |           +---------------------------------- uint32_t        ncmds;          // Number of commands this library proivides. 0, this is a redundant library.
|           |           |           +---------------------------------------------- uint32_t        filetype;       // Once again, documentation is lacking in this department, yet I don't think it particularly matters for our useless library.
|           |           +---------------------------------------------------------- cpu_subtype_t   cpusubtype;     // Like cputype, this suggests what systems this can run on. Here, 0 is ANY.
|           +---------------------------------------------------------------------- cpu_type_t      cputype;        // Defines what cpus this can run on, I guess. -1 is ANY. This library is definitely cross system compatible.
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- uint32_t        magic;          // This number seems to be provided by the compiling system, as I lack a system to compile Mach-O, I can't retrieve the actual value for this. But it will always be 4 bytes. (On 32bit systems)
```

Consists entirely of the header, and does not need the data nor the cmds. This is, by nature, the smallest Mach-O binary possible. It might not run correctly on any conceivable hardware, but it matches the specification.

I'd supply the actual file, but it entirely consists of unprintable characters.

Comment: The very first line of description starts with "once again". I'm guessing you wrote them in a different order.

Comment: Read bottom to top, which is like left to right. Yes, I wrote them in that order.

Comment: This doesn't actually *run* in any meaningful sense, though.

Comment: Although it doesn't technically run in any _meaningful sense_ is is technically run-able. Assuming the specification is correct, this is a library without any data. Or, more simply, just the header of a library.

Comment: How can this be run? Putting it in a binary file and executing it throws an error saying "Exec format error"

Comment: The Error is almost definitely in the Magic part of the Header, for which I can't actually get the 4 bytes for. Unless someone can find me the x86 Magic Number.

Answer (score 1):

(uint)0x00000007 is "I386" and "X86" (name depending upon where in the XNU spec you are looking, but it's the correct arch)
(uint)0x0x01000007 is X86_64

Theoretically, you can OR any CPU value with 0x1000000 to make it a 64bit version.  XNU seems to not always consider them discrete values; e.g., ARM 32 and 64 are 0x0000000C and 0x0100000C, respectively.

Ah heck, here's the list I wound up having to figure out a few years back, note that most of these predate OS/X:

```
VAX       =          1,    // Little-Endian
ROMP      =          2,    // Big-Endian -- 24bit or 32bit
NS32032   =          4,    // Hybrid -- Treat as Little Endian -- First 32b procs on the market
NS32332   =          5,    // Hybrid -- Treat as Little Endian -- These introduced a 20 byte "instruction cache"
MC680x0   =          6,    // Big-Endian
X86       =          7,    // Little-Endian
I386      =          7,    // alias for X86 and gets used interchangeably
MIPS      =          8,    // Big-Endian
NS32532   =          9,    // Hybrid -- Treat as Little Endian -- These ran from 20MHz up to a stunning 30MHz
MC98000   =         10,    // Big-Endian
HPPA      =         11,    // Big-Endian
ARM       =         12,    // Both! -- will treat as Little-Endian by default
MC88000   =         13,    // Big-Endian
SPARC     =         14,    // Big-Endian
I860      =         15,    // Little-Endian
ALPHA     =         16,    // Big-Endian -- NB, this is a 64-bit CPU, but seems to show up w/o the ABI64 flag . . . 
POWERPC   =         18,    // Big-Endian
X86_64    =   16777223,    // Little-Endian
POWERPC64 =   16777234,    // Big-Endian
ARM_64    = 0x0100000C     // Both! -- wil treat as Little-Endian by default
```